# Navigation between fragments using BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments

There's a `NavigationView` that opens a fragment, in that fragment there's a `BottomNavigationView`. The bottom navigation view, should switch between two fragments.

Note: When the app starts, it opens the first **blank** fragment (called `Home`), so when I click on the second menu item it opens another fragment (that contains the bottom navigation).

I tried to switch from one fragment to the other using `FragmentTransaction` in this way:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            final Fragment fragment;
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_alert) {
                fragment = new IPAlertFragment();
            } else {
                fragment = new IPStatsFragment();
            }
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).commit();
            return false;
        }
    };
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

It works fine when I open the fragment from the navigation menu for the first time, but when I click a second time on the navigation menu, the `BottomNavigationView.onNavigationItemSelectedListener` doesn't fire anymore and I can't switch from a fragment to the other.

So, I've tried to accomplish my goal using `NavController`, like the following:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            final NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavFragment.this);
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_alert) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_openAlert);
            } else {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_openStats);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

But when I navigate to the other fragment the left menu bar change the icon to "back arrow", it's a kind of new activity, and I have to use the back button (or the menu back icon) in order to show the previous tab.

I would like to navigate to a destination fragment overriding the current "screen", as like as the side menu does.

Here is the `mobile_navigation.xml`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_ip_alert"
    android:name="IPAlertFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_ip"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_i_p_alert">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_openStats"
        app:destination="@id/nav_ip_stats"
        app:launchSingleTop="false" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_ip_stats"
    android:name="IPStatsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_ip"
    tools:layout="@layout/stats_tabs">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_openAlert"
        app:destination="@id/nav_ip_alert"
        app:launchSingleTop="false" />
</fragment>
```

I don't know what's wrong (espacially with the first solution) any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem:

> It works fine when I open the fragment from the navigation menu for the first time, but when I click a second time on the navigation menu, the BottomNavigationView.onNavigationItemSelectedListener doesn't fire anymore and I can't switch from a fragment to the other.

The problem was caused by the navigation menu, the listener wasn't called because I used in my activity:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

That overrides my `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, so I removed that line and I've setted my listener as the following:

```
final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
            boolean handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
            if (handled) {
                ViewParent parent = navigationView.getParent();
                if (parent instanceof DrawerLayout) {
                    ((DrawerLayout) parent).closeDrawer(navigationView);
                }
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Here's a piece of NavigationUI that override my listener:

```
public static void setupWithNavController(@NonNull final NavigationView navigationView,
        @NonNull final NavController navController) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    boolean handled = onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
                    //******* CUTTED ***************
                    return handled;
                }
            });
}
```

So, replacing the `setupWithNavController`, I can navigate through the tabs correctly.